# Completed 500 Internal Server Error and ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify

I'm using Shopify, Ruby on Rails and Heroku postgres and I keep getting this error:

> ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess (Failed.  Response code = 403.  Response message = Forbidden.) and Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 210ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

I'm trying to CRUD the Shopify's data to another app which is from rails and I tried migrating the database and heroku logs to figure out the problem but I found none.

This is my controller code

```
def index
  @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
  @webhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all)
end

def show
  @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
end

def create
  @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.new(params.require(:product).permit(:title))
  if @products.save
    redirect_to home_index
  else
    render :index
  end 
end
```

Here's my routing

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :home
  post 'home/new', to: 'home#create'
end
```

My new.html.erd

```
<%= form_for :product do |f| %>
  <p> 
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p> 

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Here's my index.html.erd

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <li><%= link_to product.title, "https://#{@shop_session.url}/admin/products/#{product.id}", target: "_top" %></li>
  <%= link_to 'Create Product', new_home_path %>     
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Kindly share your error screen shot for find out issues.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it barely tells us anything. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. Start with `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You are making calls to the API and you are NOT authenticated, so you get back a 403. You need to first open up an authenticated session, and then make your calls to the API. For example:

```
session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop, token)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session) if session.valid?
```